# Add unique constraint based on field value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, constraints

For the following table:

[image]

I'd like to add a constraint that if IsBanned flag is set to true, the BannedOn field cannot be left empty (cannot be set to null).

How can I do this in MySQL? Here's my CREATE syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fa_ranking_system`.`Player` (
  `PlayerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_ServerID` INT NOT NULL,
  `PlayerName` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `RegDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `IsBanned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedOn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedBy` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `BannedOn` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerID`, `FK_ServerID`),
  INDEX `fk_Player_Server_idx` (`FK_ServerID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Player_Server`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_ServerID`)
    REFERENCES `fa_ranking_system`.`Server` (`ServerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: That would be a `CHECK` constraint, not a `UNIQUE` constraint (standard SQL), but they're not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can **not** define conditional structures in DDL syntax. Your field can be either `NULL` or `NOT NULL` - there's no third option (and it cannot depend of another field *in structure*)

But you can still emulate desired behavior via triggers. You can interrupt `UPDATE`/`INSERT` statement if incoming data is invalid in terms of your logic. That can be done via:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `bannedOnCheck`
BEFORE INSERT ON `fa_ranking_system`.`Player`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF(new.IsBanned && new.BannedOn IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL 'Integrity check failed: can not set banned without ban date'
  END IF
END
```